# Overflow error when use OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbcommand

I use `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` for insert data in access database.

My code:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Sources\MyProject\App_Data\Tax\TTMS.mdb";            
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO table 1(value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10) Values (@value1,@value2,@value3,@value4,@value5,@value6,@value7,@value8,@value9,@value10)", conn)
OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO table 2(value11,value12,value13,value14,value15,value16,value17) Values (@value11,@value12,@value13,@value14,@value15,@value16,@value17)", conn)
SqlDataReader droledb = GETDATA();

if (droledb.HasRows)
{
    while (droledb.Read())
    {
        if(table1)  
        {
            command1.Parameters.Add("value1", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value1;
            command1.Parameters.Add("value2", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value2;
            command1.Parameters.Add("value3", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value3;
            command1.Parameters.Add("value4", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value4;
            command1.Parameters.Add("value5", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value5;
            command1.Parameters.Add("value6", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value6;
            command1.Parameters.Add("value7", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value7;
            command1.Parameters.Add("value8", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value8;
            command1.Parameters.Add("value9", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value9;
            command1.Parameters.Add("value10", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value10;
            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        else(table2)
        {
            command2.Parameters.Add("value11", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value11;
            command2.Parameters.Add("value12", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value12;
            command2.Parameters.Add("value13", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value13;
            command2.Parameters.Add("value14", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value14;
            command2.Parameters.Add("value15", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value15;
            command2.Parameters.Add("value16", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value16;
            command2.Parameters.Add("value17", OleDbType.Integer).Value = value17;
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

`command1.ExecuteNonQuery();` works but `command2.ExecuteNonQuery();` does not work and I get this error:

```
[Message] 
Overflow
```

StackTrace:

```
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Total_pgTest3.btnOK_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Sources\MyProject\Total\pgTest3.aspx.cs:line 200
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

thanks.

Comment: This is not a enough error information. What is your stack trace?

Comment: In some way it is too much information, could you shrink your example to use either smaller tables or only one table?

Comment: missing semicolon OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO table 1(value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10) Values (@value1,@value2,@value3,@value4,@value5,@value6,@value7,@value8,@value9,@value10)", conn) // ; is required, are you sure your code compile?

Comment: @Infer-On My Code Runs well and not error as command1 . my error when command2.ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: You are passing all parameters as integers. The overflow error seems to indicate that someone of your fields is not big enough to contain the integer value passed. (Are all integers the values passed right?)

Comment: @Steve No.type Many value is OleDbType.VarChar.

Comment: So are you reading VarChar data (strings) then pass them to parameters of type Integer leaving the burden of the conversion to the OleDb engine? Well, that's a fine recipe for problems. You should pass the correct value expected by the parameter (an integer) converting yourself the values loaded by the reader. And the parameter should be the exact type expected by the receiving field. Implicit conversions are evil.